# How to marshal float array from c# to c, and then edit array in c while having c# be able to reference the updated array instantly

Tags: c#, pointers, marshalling

I am not sure if this is possible, I don't know a whole lot about marshaling in c#, so please fill me in on my understanding of this if I am way off, or if this is possible at all.

But basically I have an array of floats in C#, in a C# based app. Every time this program cycles I need to do some very processor intensive heavy lifting on this array of floats. So I wanted to write this processor heavy code in C, and then marshall the array of floats over to C and handle there editing in C. Which seems simple enough, but the thing is my C# code needs to have immediate access to the float array that was edited in C.

The problem I have run into is the overhead of marshaling. Any gains in performance are lost in the process of marshaling. If I have to marshall this array of floats from C# to C, then back from C to C# every cycle of this program, there isn't any performance gain.

Is there some way that I can make an array of floats and marshal the pointer to this array over to C, and edit the array in C. But also be able to use that same exact pointer from C# to immediately reference the array and see what the C code has changed in the array? So then I don't have to marshall the array back and forth every cycle?

Comment: There are very few cases where the pinvoke marshaller creates a copy of the array.  Normal marshaling involves pinning the array and passing a pointer to the elements of the managed float[].  You can tell this happens when you can actually see the changes made by the C code without using the [Out] attribute.  Don't make assumptions, measure first.  Then post code if you found a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28VS.80%29.aspx) block.  This will prevent the garbage collector from moving the array in memory.  As a consequence, you get a raw pointer to the managed array that you can use.  Pass the raw pointer to your C code.  No copying necessary: the C code will operate directly on the managed array.  Just don't retain the raw pointer once the fixed block goes out of scope, or you could be holding a bad pointer after the GC runs.

Example:

```
int[] arr;
// NOT SHOWN:  initialize arr array
fixed (int* p = arr) {
    // NOT SHOWN:  call C function, passing "p" pointer
}
```